# How to continue downloading file after disconnection?

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I have simple java-server via sockets.
Server is read from client url of file which need to download.

```
    FileOutputStream outStream= new FileOutputStream(SERVER_PATH + file.getName());

    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(outStream);
    byte buf[] = new byte[BATCH];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = in.read(buf,0,BATCH))>=0){

        out.write(buf,0,read);

    }
```

how to continue to download file?

Comment: Download after disconnecting? How? By magic? ESP? How do you propose to get electrons through your wires if there is no connection?

Comment: perhaps David Blaine or Chris Angel can do it for you

Comment: Nothing magic! We have connection after disconnection again. Sorry, I probably wrote it is not clear..

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is a little ambiguous .!

After looking at the code, it looks like you are reading from a File in Client machine and Writing the same to the Server URL.
Assuming this situation,

The points that can help you resolve this are,
1. There will an IOException if the connection is lost. That means you have to handle the exception and reconnect to the Socket. May be after waiting for some time (!!)
2. Then you need to open the server File in Append mode and continue with out.write. As the out is not reset or lost with the Disconnection.

Thanks, Sunil